# Connect Gatsby with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, graphql, gatsby

I would like to pull data from Postgres to Gatsby using graphql. I have written node.js server, but i cannot find way to use it in gatsby.
(https://github.com/gstuczynski/graphql-postgres-test)
Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is implement a source plugin as seen here https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/create-source-plugin/.

There are many examples within the gatsby repository that implement the source api.  See those for inspiration!  Basically you need to translate the contents of your Postgres db into a format gatsby understands.  Gatsby calls this format “nodes”.

You could implement a plugin which interfaces with your db directly or with whatever api your node server exposes (graphql, REST etc.).

Answer (score 3):

The [`gatsby-source-pg`](https://github.com/graphile/gatsby-source-pg) module connects directly to your database and adds the tables/views/functions/etc to Gatsby's GraphQL API. To use it, install the module:

```
yarn add gatsby-source-pg
```

then add to to the plugin list in `gatsby-config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    /* ... */
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-pg",
      options: {
        connectionString: "postgres://localhost/my_db",
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

*The connection string can also include username/password, host, port and SSL if you need to connect to remote database; e.g.: `postgres://pg_user:pg_pass@pg_host:5432/pg_db?ssl=1`*

You can query it in your components using the root `postgres` field, e.g.:

```graphql
{
  postgres {
    allPosts {
      nodes {
        id
        title
        authorId
        userByAuthorId {
          id
          username
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gatsby now supports an arbitrary GraphQL endpoint as a source which will help: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-graphql/

---

You can also use [Hasura](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine) to give you an instant GraphQL API on Postgres and then query that from your Gatsby app. You can follow the tutorial [here](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/tree/master/community/sample-apps/gatsby-postgres-graphql).

**Step1:** Deploy Hasura against your existing Postgres database: https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/getting-started/using-existing-database.html

**Step 2:** Install the `gatsby-source-graphql` plugin for gatsby: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-graphql/

**Step 3:** Configure the plugin

```
{
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-graphql', // <- Configure plugin
      options: {
        typeName: 'HASURA',
        fieldName: 'hasura', // <- fieldName under which schema will be stitched
        createLink: () =>
          createHttpLink({
            uri: `https://my-graphql.herokuapp.com/v1alpha1/graphql`, // <- Configure connection GraphQL url
            headers: {},
            fetch,
          }),
        refetchInterval: 10, // Refresh every 10 seconds for new data
      },
    },
  ]
}
```

**Step 4:** Make the GraphQL query in your component

```
const Index = ({ data }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>My Authors </h1>
    <AuthorList authors={data.hasura.author} />
  </div>
)
export const query = graphql`
  query AuthorQuery {
    hasura {        # <- fieldName as configured in the gatsby-config
      author {      # Normal GraphQL query
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
```

Other links:

- Sample-app/tutorial:
  https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/tree/master/community/sample-apps/gatsby-postgres-graphql
- Blogpost:
  https://blog.hasura.io/create-gatsby-sites-using-graphql-on-postgres-603b5dd1e516

Note: I work at Hasura.